# Ros-kinetic error: pcl_ros cannot find openmpi

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this problem building the ros packages for my project.
I am running ros-kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ros_sourcesink'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_sourcesink)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Warning: ros_sourcesink_clothoid_lane_ros_marker_sink -- not building library, missing [icl_traffic_maps_utilities].
-- Warning: ros_sourcesink_chm_values_ros_marker_sink -- not building library, missing [icl_traffic_maps_gtsam_utilities].
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ros_automated_driving'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_automated_driving)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/pcl_ros/cmake/pcl_rosConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'pcl_ros' specifies '/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/opt/ros/kinetic//usr/include/hdf5/openmpi'.  Ask the maintainer 'Paul
  Bovbel <paul@bovbel.com>, Bill Morris <bill@neautomation.com>' to fix it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  ros_automated_driving/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250080/ros-kinetic-error:-pcl_ros-cannot-find-openmpi/) by [ignacioalvmar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28802/ignacioalvmar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on 2020-12-01**:
although this question is quite old, the problem just recently popped up again:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/1058

any ideas how to properly solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a PCL include. I've verified on a clean install that if you apt-get install ros-kinetic-pcl-ros from debians, or run `rosdep install` to pull in dependencies on a source workspace containing pcl_ros, the path will exist on your system.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it installing the library. Thought ros would install it already.
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-openmpi-dev

---

Originally posted by [ignacioalvmar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28802/ignacioalvmar/) with karma: 31 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-15**:
Are you building things from sources? If you are, you are responsible for installing dependences (using `rosdep`). If you aren't this would be something to report over at the `pcl_ros` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues).

**Comment by [bugfighter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32802/bugfighter/) on 2017-11-29**:
I was facing the same issue running ros-kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, even after purge of **ros-kinetic-pcl-ros**, **libpcl-dev** and then
**rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y**

this issue only got resolved after
**sudo apt-get install libhdf5-openmpi-dev**